# How to add "Load More" functionality in Select2 bootstrap searchable for Jquery by using Eloquent Pagination from Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I was able to implement a searchable drop down thanks to the help of select2 bootstrap. If I click the dropdown, it will show on the first row a search pane where I could type the name of the user and at the same time, I could manually pick it by scrolling down.

However, if the data already reaches 3000, the dropdown shows until the bottom which looks messy. So to tidy up things, I would like to limit the users displayed by only 10 and the last row is a "Load more...". If I scrolled the scroll bar at the bottom-most part, it should load the next 10 which is done through getting the next 10 users from the UsersController. I use paginate from the controller so I have no problem with this.

My problem is how can I detect the scrollbar is reaching the bottom, so that I can tell the select2 bootstrap to load the next 10 users? The select2 bootstrap creates a search bar, and the scrollable dropdown list dynamically, if I press the dropdown and I can't figure out how I can detect if the scroll bar already reached the bottom.

`users.blade.php`

```
@section('script')
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/localization/messages_ja.js" defer></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" defer/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@1.3.4/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" defer/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" defer>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            let setUserSelectList = function (data) {
                let $sel = $('#userId');
                $sel.children('option:gt(0)').remove();
                
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    let status = !value.is_active ? ' (' + value.status_name + ')' : '';
                    $sel.append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + status + '</option>');
                });

                $sel.append('<option>' + 'Load more...' + '</option>');

                $sel.select2({
                    data: data,
                    theme: 'bootstrap4'
                });

                return $sel;
            };

            $('#create-meter').click(function () {
                $.when(
                    $.get('user/select-list', function (data) {
                        setUserSelectList(data);
                    })
                ).done(function() {
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
     <div class="row mt-1 col-sm-10">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary " id="create-meter">Fetch Users</a>
        <label for="userId" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control" id="userId" name="user_id" required>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`UsersController.php`

```
public function listForSelect()
{
    // $userList = User::paginate(4); //I wanted to implement this  
    $userList = User::all();  
    return response()->json($userList);
}
```

Comment: Target the select2 drop-down and attach scroll event to it, also a minimal html/CSS/js example would be much helpful

Comment: @Ainz-sama thanks for the reply, I updated it again and added the HTML part. The code is really huge so I just chopped the necessary parts here